# Laravel 7 - Update value of checkbox without form or button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, checkbox

I'm stuck with my project, please help...

This is the situation: In my project I have to assign a teacher to give permission to grade students, because a group can have 2 or more teachers, but only one has to have permission to grade, so... I added a column in my table 'teachers' in the database with the name 'grade' of type boolean. And in my view I added a checkbox... How do I change the value of a checkbox without using any form or button to trigger the action and activate the checkbox in the teacher who is going to have permission to grade? And this value should also be updated in the database.

- This is my view...

```
    <!--teachers-->
    <table class=" table table-sm table-striped table-bordered ">
        <thead class="text-white bg-primary">
            <tr>
                <th>@lang('show.Identifier')</th>
                <th>@lang('show.email')</th>
                <th>@lang('show.grade')</th>
                <th>@lang('show.delete')</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody class="small text-center">
            @foreach ($group->teachers as $teacher)
                <tr>
                    <td >{{$teacher->Identifier}} </td>
                    <td >{{$teacher->email}} </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="active" {{$teacher->grade == 1 ?'checked':''}} type="checkbox" name="grade" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form method="post" action="{{url('Groups/Disenroll/'.$group->idGroup.'?idTeacher='.$teacher->idTeacher)}}">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                            <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger"  > <i class="material-icons small" >call_split</i></button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And this is an image of the table, if it helps...

[image: teachers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use something like JQuery for this.

You can firstly add a class of **toggle-class** to your checkbox

```
<input class="active toggle-class" {{$teacher->grade == 1 ?'checked':''}} type="checkbox" name="grade">
```

And secondly, make sure that you have a way to keep track of who's doing the grades.

Add **data-id="{{ $teacher->Identifier}}"** on your checkbox

```
<input data-id="{{ $teacher->Identifier}}" class="active toggle-class" {{$teacher->grade == 1 ?'checked':''}} type="checkbox" name="grade">
```

In your **web.php** add a new route

```
Route::get('/path/to/updateGrader/status', [App\Http\Controllers\MyController::class, 'updateGraderStatus']);
```

Add the below code to where your checkbox is located

```
$('.toggle-class').on('change',function(){
    let status = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? true : false;
    let grader_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       dataType:'json',
       url:'/path/to/updateGrader/status', // add your earlier created route here
       data:{'grade': status, 'grader_id': grader_id},
       success: function(data){
        console.log('success');
     }
   });
});
```

In your Controller, **MyController** in our case create a new function

```
public function updateGraderStatus(Request $request)
{
       $grader = MyModel::find($request->grader_id);
       $grader->grade = $request->grade;
       $grader->save(); 
}
```

Please let me know if this helps you. I didn't test it out but I think this is how you would go about it.

Comment: It gives me this error 500 (Internal Server Error). The full response on the console is this: `jquery.js:9664 GET http://localhost/Servescol2.0.2/public/Groups/StatusGrade?grade=0&id=hframosb 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: This type of error tends to mostly be related to a controller function or web.php. Since you're using Laravel 7 did you write the route definition as per Laravel 7? E.g. Route::get('/path/to/updateGrader/status', 'MyController@updateGraderStatus');?

Comment: Yes, this is my route: Route::get('StatusGrade', 'GroupController@UpdateStatusGrade')->middleware('auth');

Comment: Click on this response to see what it's complaining about. I think this link should be clickable if I'm not mistaken:  jquery.js:9664 GET http://localhost/Servescol2.0.2/public/Groups/StatusGrade?grade=0&id=hframosb 500 (Internal Server Error) on your console I mean

Comment: I think it's this error: ErrorException
Trying to get property 'identifier' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Servescol2.0.2\resources\views\group\show.blade.php). But it doesn't make sense, because this property it was working fine. Is in the same view, but it had not caused me problems before.

Comment: I think I have to pass another data in ajax? Because the grade is on the group, it filters teachers from that group specifically

Comment: Ah nice catch. I agree. Pass the group id to the ajax and then check the group in your controller. update it using the relationship

Comment: I put this on my Controller `$teacher = Teacher::where('idTeacher',$idTeacher)->first();
        $group= $teacher ->groups()->where('groups.idGroup',$idGroup)->first();
        $group->pivot->grade= $request->grader_id;
        $grupo->pivot->save();`
But how do I pass the group id to the ajax? Sorry, I'm not good at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241366/discussion-between-steven-selolo-and-many-rodriguez).